# I want to know if there are any Dork commands for the Telegram search bar similar just like Google?

Tags: search, telegram

I want to know if the searchbar in Telegram has a similar system like Google where you could limit your search results based on specific commands?

For example limiting timeframes.
Example Google: daterange:startdate-enddate

Putting a minus before a word I didn't wanted in the search result.